# Invoking For Loops VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, loops

How do I invoke a for loop in VB.Net?

Example:

```
    For Each listViewItem As ListViewItem In Me.TaskListView.Items
        Me.ExecuteTask(listViewItem, False)
    Next
```

So that needs to be invoked, but how do I go about that? I am not sure how. This is inside my background worker handler and causes an InvalidOperationException when inside it. The extra information for the error is: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TaskListView' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

The error occurs on this line:

```
    For Each listViewItem As ListViewItem In Me.TaskListView.Items
```

Comment: InvalidOperationException? Are you modifying the `listViewItem` inside `ExecuteTask`?

Comment: Yes I am. Keeping in mind it works when not inside the background worker. EDIT: It also shows the error on the first line (the "for each") line.

Comment: Posting the trace back and the exact line where it fails can help. Normally when you modify an iterable during an iteration fails.

Comment: I edited my previous comment to say where it fails, (on the first line), but how can I obtain the trace back?

Comment: Just extra, not only does it say InvalidOperationException, but this is the extra bit: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TaskListView' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: It will help to edit your question with that information, so other can see it an narrow the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcome problems with threads in winforms using the following subroutine

```
Public Sub GuiAsync(ByVal frm As Form, ByVal action As Action)
    If action IsNot Nothing Then
        If frm.InvokeRequired Then
            frm.Invoke(action)
        Else
            action()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I'd use it as follows (in case your code runs in a Form and Me is reference to the Form):

```
 GuiAsync(Me,
    Sub()
       For Each listViewItem As ListViewItem In Me.TaskListView.Items
           Me.ExecuteTask(listViewItem, False)
       Next
    End Sub)
```